# Replace selected row values based on certain column

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I would like to find rows in `df` where `C` contains `X1` and replace value in `A` with value in `C` and, replace value in `C` with value in `result1`(shift values in `C` and `result1` to the leftmost).

`df`:

```
   A        C      result1   result2
0  NaN      X1     10/10/10  NaN
1  TEXT:    >1     TEXT       <1
2  NaN      X1     10/11/11  <10
```

Expected output:

```
   A        C         result1    result2
0  X1       10/10/10  NaN        NaN         
1  TEXT:    >1        TEXT       <1
2  X1       10/11/11  NaN        <10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mask` and `shift`:

```
subset = df.loc[:, "A":"result1"]
df.loc[:, "A":"result1"] = subset.mask(df.C.eq("X1"), subset.shift(-1, axis=1))
```

For the rows that `C` equals to `"X1"`, the locations in the `subset` are filled with shifted `subset`.

to get

```
>>> df

       A         C result1 result2
0     X1  10/10/10     NaN     NaN
1  TEXT:        >1    TEXT      <1
2     X1  10/11/11     NaN     <10
```